# how to write a scope for a model that belongs_to two other models and excludes all records with matching foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to write a scope for a model that belongs_to two other models. This scope should select all records where the value of one model is not equal to the value of its parent. What I have below seems like it should work:

```
Class Blob
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :item

 scope: :not_owned_by_item_owner, ->  { where.not(user_id: item.owner.id) }
end
```

But then calling `blob.not_owned_by_item_owner` anywhere in a controller results in an `undefined local variable or method` error for `item`. Why is `item` not recognized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution 1

```
scope :not_owned_by_item_owner, -> {
  joins(:item).where.not(
    Blob.arel_table[:user_id].eq(Item.arel_table[:owner_id])
  )
}
# SELECT  "blobs".* FROM "blobs" INNER JOIN "items" ON "items"."id" = "blobs"."item_id" WHERE "blobs"."user_id" != "items"."owner_id"
```

### Solution 2

or if you prefer raw SQL:

```
scope :not_owned_by_item_owner, -> {
  joins(:item).where('blobs.user_id != items.owner_id')
}
# SELECT  "blobs".* FROM "blobs" INNER JOIN "items" ON "items"."id" = "blobs"."item_id" WHERE (blobs.user_id != items.owner_id) LIMIT $1
```

*P.S. I don't think there's an `ActiveRecord` native solution for this, but I am also interested if anyone finds one. The above Solution 1 uses `Arel` directly.*

Comment: This works. Thank you so much. Looks like my confusion was in when to use `where.not` vs `!=`. From your answer, it looks like one should not use `where.not` for equality comparisons. Im a dum dum.